# How to slice out certain rows and columns and then take only the remaining data in Dataframe Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this

```
Unnamed: 0           Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2  ... Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
0         NaN                  NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN
1         NaN                  NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN
2         NaN                 Date       Open  ...        Low     Close      Volume
3         NaN  2017-09-14 00:00:00     1493.2  ...     1489.4    1530.31  591178000
4         NaN  2017-09-13 00:00:00     1502.2  ...    1483.96     1493.2  591178000
```

I would like to take only the data from 3rd row, for that I would be doing something like this `df[2:]` and then make it the column.

But I am not sure about how to slice the column now to skip the first column.
I am quite new at Pandas so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

Replace the `Unnamed` column labels with values from row 2:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[2]
```

Keep only valid rows and columns, specifically rows 3 onward, and columns 1 onward:

```
df = df.iloc[3:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your dataframe by

```
df=df.dropna(thresh=1).T.set_index(2).T
```